# DirectX11 can write minus value to texture formatted float?

Tags: directx

I'd like to write normal value to texture formatted DXGI_FORMAT_R11G11B10_FLOAT.
I know that write "0.5 * normal + 0.5"  works well.
But my texture format is float so I tried writing unpacked normal and it did not work.
Does DirectX11 support minus value texture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DXGI_FORMAT_R11G11B10_FLOAT` is a positive only format. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgiformat/ne-dxgiformat-dxgi_format).

> Three partial-precision floating-point numbers encoded into a single 32-bit value (a variant of s10e5, which is sign bit, 10-bit mantissa, and 5-bit biased (15) exponent).
> **There are no sign bits**, and there is a 5-bit biased (15) exponent for each channel, 6-bit mantissa for R and G, and a 5-bit mantissa for B, as shown in the following illustration.

If you want to write negative floating-point values to a render target, you need to use a different format.

```
DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT
DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT
```

`DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT` is also an option, but support for this format as a render target is not required for any Direct3D hardware feature level. You have to check for support and have a fallback when it's not supported.